# Automatically populating Jira with a set of tasks and dependencies?

Tags: jira

I have a text file containing an outline of some tasks I wish to track.

Is it possible to take a textual description similar to the following and somehow automatically create Jira tasks and dependencies?

I am fine with default values being assigned to the various fields and filling them in later, I would just like to avoid the tedium of entering and linking each ticket by hand.

```
upgrade service:
  upgrade service on gcp staging:
    upgrade database:
    upgrade server:
  upgrade service on aws staging:
    upgrade database:
    upgrade server:
  test service on gcp staging:
  test service on aws staging:
  upgrade service on gcp prod:
    upgrade database:
    upgrade server:
  upgrade service on aws prod:
    upgrade database:
    upgrade server:
  verify service on gcp prod:
  verify service on aws prod:
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a different approach. I prefer to define the tasks that make up my planning in MS Project. From MS Project I publish them in Jira. This can be fully automated using MS Project add-ins. I have tested a few and my favorite est Ceptah Bridge. You can have a look here: https://www.ceptah.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to represent these textual descriptions on Jira as tasks. You can represent each task with a code or an assigned topic in the user stories column, then write your description in the "requirement" space.
For dependency, you can easily do this on the VMB provided in Jira and link each dependency to one another.
Once you have enough task identified as user stories in your backlog with your work flow written in VMB, your roadmap will identify that and show you a graphical image showing the dependency and relationship between each task.
Hope this helps.